# C# Connecting to remote oracle database. ORA-12154 Could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have written an application which connects to an Oracle 10g database. From one computer it works fine but from another it errors. Neither computer is the database server.

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

The connection string used:

```
private string = "provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=192.168.1.5/MyInstance;User Id=username;Password=password";
private OleDbDataAdapter oda = oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
private OleDbConnection oracleConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString.ToString());
```

However the computer where it works is the database server for another oracle instance!

My application needs to be able to connect to the oracle instance from any computer.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Ive tried this [What is the exact format of a connection string for Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076524/what-is-the-exact-format-of-a-connection-string-for-oracle) but couldnt get any of the options to work.

EDIT: I found a connection string that works.

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.5)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MyInstanceID)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id = myusername; Password = mypassword;
```

Comment: Try to connect trough sql developer.

Comment: Ya works from SQL Developer. Is there a way to see the connection string used by SQL Developer?

Comment: Do you have an Oracle Client installed? Have you created a TNS Entry for your database? Can you TNSPING the database?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can connect trough SqlDeveloper then this supposed to be an issue related to your connection string. I'm not quite sure is there a way to get SqlDeveloper's connection string. Verify your connection string with [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/oracle) variants.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of playing about the following connection string works for me.

Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.5)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MyInstanceID)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id = myusername; Password = mypassword;

Comment: Yes, that is what you normally put in a TNSNAMES file and then you would simply reference the TNS entry. Hard coding TNS entries in connection strings is not good practice.

Comment: Im not going to have a TNSNAME file because the computer the application is running on does not have oracle installed.

Comment: But by using the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider you actually *are* using an Oracle client. i.e. Oracle is installed.

Comment: @Ciaran You are correct. I missed that. How can i connect without having oracle client installed.

Comment: @CathalMF, actually you can. I did this before, all you need to do is put locally ALL referenced assemblies and provide connection string as you described.

Comment: @DenysDenysenko What assemblies do i need to place locally or the above oracle provider?

Comment: @CathalMF, this have been long time ago so I have no access to this project anymore and I can't name exact assembly names, sorry.

Comment: That mechanism is messy and not supported. It is also fairly much unsupportable by the developer. I'm afraid that you will have to install the oracle client. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but it's something I've struggled with for years.

Comment: @Ciarán well thats a bit rubbish. Ah well ill just have to make do. Thanks.